# WebDriverException: chrome not reachable on trying to close multiple windows

Tags: selenium, qt, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium Java to test an application that implements a QT chromium based browser and shows web pages that I need to test inside that browser. I am using ChromeDriver 2.43.600233
and set app name to "Chrome" and version to "69.0.3497.128".

I face no issues closing the application using a loop on all of the tabs and `driver.close()` , until a webpage opens another page but in a separate window. Trying to loop on all of the tabs by either starting by the tab in the main window or the tab in the second window throws that exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
```

on the first call to `driver.close()` . I tried replacing `driver.close()` with

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.open('','_self').close()");
```

but it fails with the same exception.
If I have multiple tabs in my window and I start the loop by closing the tabs in the first window, `driver.close()` only starts failing with the last tab in the main window. Then it fails on switching to the tab in the second window with the same exception. Starting with the tab in the second window, the window closes successfully but I get a pop up

> Are you sure you want to close the window ? There are 2 tabs open.

which belongs to the main window although I still didn't switch to any tab in the main window and the code stucks at the call to `driver.close()` issued to the tab in the second window until it timeouts. However, I tried disabling the pop up using the solution mentioned in https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/33301/how-to-handle-browser-closing-popup
but I still get the pop up.

`driver.quit();` never worked for me even in the case of a single tab and it prints

```
May 05, 2021 1:14:36 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess destroy
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). [/u/prod/chromedriver/chromedriver, --port=17129][ {}]
May 05, 2021 1:14:37 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess destroy
SEVERE: Unable to kill process with PID 7949
```

and the app never closes and I don't find any process with the mentioned process id.

Comment: To be able to close browser window (except the initial one) you need to switch driver to the window. See https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/window-handle-in-selenium/

Comment: I want to close all of the windows not the first one only. I tried looping and switching to all of the window handlers but that gave me the same results as working with tabs. And for some reason although I have 2 tabs in a window and 1 in the other, I get 3 window handlers.